# Are there any performance or coding issues with passing an object to multiple pages as a way to share variables for tabbed pages?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using a tabbed page like this:

```
public partial class MainPage : TabbedPage
{

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var phrasesPage = new NavigationPage(new PhrasesPage())
        {
            Title = "Play",
            Icon = "play.png"
        };
        ....
        Children.Add(phrasesPage);
        Children.Add(categoriesPage);
        Children.Add(favoritesPage);
        Children.Add(settingsPage);
        Children.Add(aboutPage);
    }
```

I want to share variables between my pages. For example a score number that will show on all pages and a few other variables.

I would like to code my application so that it's easy to maintain.

```
public partial class MainPage : TabbedPage
{

   public class Person
   {
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public int Age { get; set; }
       public Person(){}
       public Person(string name, int age)
       {
           Name = name;
           Age = age;
       }
    }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var person = Person p=new Person()
        {
           Name = "Han Solo",
           Age = 39
        };

        var phrasesPage = new NavigationPage(new PhrasesPage(person))
        {
            Title = "Play",
            Icon = "play.png"
        };
        ....
        ....
        Children.Add(phrasesPage);
        Children.Add(categoriesPage);
        Children.Add(favoritesPage);
        Children.Add(settingsPage);
        Children.Add(aboutPage);
    }
```

Can someone advise me if it would be good to create an object that contains all the shared variables and then to pass that object to the constructor of each of the pages as a parameter when the pages are created with a "new"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We created a class to store and retrieve objects in and out of a static dictionary of objects, it sits in our PCL, but could be used in Forms as it's generic compilable code.

Create the class:

```
public static class ApplicationState
{
    private static Dictionary<string, object> _values =
               new Dictionary<string, object>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets a value in the dictionary with the entered values.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key"></param>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    public static void SetValue(string key, object value)
    {
        if (_values.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            _values.Remove(key);
        }
        _values.Add(key, value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the object with the associated entered key.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="key"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static T GetValue<T>(string key)
    {
        if (_values.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            return (T)_values[key];
        }
        else
        {
            return default(T);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Clears all values from the ApplicationState
    /// </summary>
    public static void ClearValues()
    {
        _values.Clear();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks if the dictionary contains a value with a key equal to the entered string
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool ContainsValue(string key)
    {
        if (_values.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets all values currently saved within the ApplicationState, in the form of a dictionary(string, object)
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Dictionary<string, object> GetAllValues()
    {
        return _values;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes a KeyValuePair from the dictionary where the key equals the entered string
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key"></param>
    public static void Remove(string key)
    {
        _values.Remove(key);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes all KeyValuePairs from the dictionary where the key starts with entered string
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="startsWith"></param>
    public static void RemoveStartsWith(string startsWith)
    {
        var toRemove = _values.Where(x => x.Key.StartsWith(startsWith))
                     .Select(pair => pair.Key)
                     .ToList();

        foreach (var key in toRemove)
        {
            _values.Remove(key);
        }
    }
}
```

the data is then set by using the following:

```
 ApplicationState.SetValue("MyKey", ObjectToStore);
```

and to retrieve it you simply use:

```
 ApplicationState.GetValue<ObjectToStore>("MyKey");
```

Edit:

So you can pull the object/variable out of the dictionary, change it, add to it etc. then simply put it back in under the same key, you could do this on page change, button click, however you want. It's really quite simple and versatile.

**Simple int and object example as requested**

Storing an int:

```
int i = 10

ApplicationState.SetValue("ThisIsANumber", i);
```

or

```
ApplicationState.SetValue("ThisIsANumber", 10);
```

Retrieving an Int

```
int variable = ApplicationState.GetValue<int>("ThisIsANumber");
```

Storing an Object

```
Object obj;

ApplicationState.SetValue("ThisIsAnObject", obj);
```

Retrieve an Object

```
Object theObject = ApplicationState.GetValue<Object>("ThisIsAnObject");
```

Comment: That looks good. So am I right in saying you just placed that code in a file in the shared project and it's ready to go and be used.

Comment: @Alan yep it's ready to go as is, i use it in most of our cross platform applications because it's so generic and easy to implement. Don't get me wrong, it won't be perfect in every situation, but it definately solves a lot of problems with passing data between pages/views etc.

Comment: If you don't mind can you give an example of storing and retrieving an int and an object.  Just a few lines.  The simplest you can come up.  Hope that it could help others also as I posted about this before but didn't get a very good answer until I changed the question a bit.

Comment: @Alan Is that ok?

Comment: I like your suggestion and will mark as correct.  Your answer is just a bit more easier to implement than the other although both are a bit help.  Is that a large Xamarin forms application you're working on?

Answer (score 2):

However you could pass it every time to a constructor, I think it would be better to create a static Singleton class to store the 'shared' values in. Than you don't always have to pass it but you just have to make a call to the class to fill/get values

A bit more information about singletons / static classes: https://www.dotnetperls.com/singleton-static

An example:

The static class where we going to keep our values in:
 public static class Test
    {

```
    public static Person person;

    static Test()
    {

    }

    public static void ResetValues() {
        person= new Person();
    }
}
```

Than in your mainpage (don't forget to add using static Test(=Name of class)) :

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
//person --> comes from the static class 

     person=new Person()
    {
       Name = "Han Solo",
       Age = 39
    };

    var phrasesPage = new NavigationPage(new PhrasesPage())
    {
        Title = "Play",
        Icon = "play.png"
    };
    ....
    ....
    Children.Add(phrasesPage);
    Children.Add(categoriesPage);
    Children.Add(favoritesPage);
    Children.Add(settingsPage);
    Children.Add(aboutPage);
}
```

Than you can acces han solo from anyway ( just call person from the static class)

Comment: If possible can you code up an example with just 5-6 lines to help me see what you mean.  BTW I added a bit to the question so maybe that makes more sense now.

Comment: @Alan I'll make an  example using a static class since i'm more used to that

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I upvoted and hope others will also upvote. I decided to accept the other answer as it's a bit more easy to implement but very much appreciate your suggestion as I think that's good also. Thanks again.